# Highlight barChart xAxis data

Tags: d3.js

I want to style some letters at xAxis from this barChart
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304

I'm getting the value for x at this step

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
```

Can I add extra div at this step, something like:

```
.attr("x", function(d) { 
    if (d.letter ==='A') svg.append('div').style('fill', 'red');
return x(d.letter); })
```

Or should use another select, like?

```
~d3.select('svg').selectAll('xAxis')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For styling xAxis texts, this would be a better option:

```
 d3.select('svg').select('g.axis.axis--x').selectAll('text')
        .style('fill', function(d) { if(d === 'A') return 'red'; });
```

> **NOTE:** .attr("x", function(d) { }) is for x position of the bar